# array, filter formula in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

=ArrayFormula(SPLIT(FILTER(IMPORTDATA("https://www.amfiindia.com/spages/NAVAll.TXT"),isnumber(left(IMPORTDATA("https://www.amfiindia.com/spages/NAVAll.TXT"),2)*1)=true,IMPORTDATA("https://www.amfiindia.com/spages/NAVAll.TXT")<>""),";"))

I get the error "filter range must be in a single row or single column" in google sheets.

This formula was working until a few days back and now i am stuck with the above error.

What is the mistake in this formula?

This formula picks up data from indian mutual funds and splits into columns with header for me todo a vlookup.

Thanks for the reponse

Trying to split into columns, data from mutual funds of india

I get the error "filter range must be in a single row or single column"

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying the formula to use the SPLIT function to convert the multi-line string of data into a single column before applying the FILTER function. This is because the error can occur when the FILTER function is trying to filter data that is not in a single row or column.

```
=ArrayFormula(SPLIT(FILTER(SPLIT(IMPORTDATA("https://www.amfiindia.com/spages/NAVAll.TXT"),CHAR(10)),isnumber(left(SPLIT(IMPORTDATA("https://www.amfiindia.com/spages/NAVAll.TXT"),CHAR(10)),2)*1)=true,SPLIT(IMPORTDATA("https://www.amfiindia.com/spages/NAVAll.TXT"),CHAR(10))<>""),";"))
```

Comment: Second this. This works - nice answer Muhammed.

Comment: Thanks and Perfect Muhammed. Works very well. Don't know why my earlier formula stopped after working for some time.

Comment: This gives #REF error first and then populates the data in the sheet. What modification do i need to this to make it work on excel? Awaiting your reply. Thanks